# "Unable To Initialize Installer" when using a softlink

Tags: lamp, symbolic-link

I've installed LAMP in ubuntu.
At the  directory it was installed, I can start the GUI if I use

```
sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run
```

However, if I create a softlink for this file:

[image: see files permisions here]

then I am getting the following problem:

[image: The problem]

- the /tmp directory presents no issues since it is writable
- there is no SELinux installed

Please advice, thank you

Comment: @Glorfindel thank you for your suggestions. The post definitely looks much better now and it is easier to understand. I'll try not to rush next time. Gracias de nuevo.